# Build gradle failed: can not identify path JDK, CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: java, spring-boot, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

Im using Gradle to build Spring Boot project. I have added environment variable for JDK Java. And then I set this JDK path in gradle.properties. When I perform to build with: *gradle myProject:bootRun*, I received an exception of JDK path wrong.

My gradle.properties:

```
jsonPathVersion=2.4.1
jsonPathAssertVersion=2.0.0
jqueryVersion=2.1.4
bootstrapVersion=3.3.4
bootswatchVersion=3.3.4+1
jqueryUiVersion=1.11.4
jqueryThemesVersion=1.11.4

# Location of local JDK for Eclipse
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91
```

This is exception when excute gradle.properties: (**UPDATED**)

```
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mvc:bootRun'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\
bin\java.exe''

Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mvc:bootRun'.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:55)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncer.java:98)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)    
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:329)
at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
... 2 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" (in directory "D:\spring-data\tto-project\mvc"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
... 6 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.035 secs
```

Although I installed and set jdk path at: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91. How Can I fix this exception ? Thank so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days, I have found a solution myself, just need:

```
1. When config, choose correct version of Gradle, plug-in Gradle STS
2. Modify the configuration in Eclipse: Perefence ->Gradle ->Gradle distribution. Select version of Gradle.
3. check Buld Model
4. JDK location is no need to change
```

I think, those will help someone when beginning Spring Boot

Comment: I faced the same issue, In my case there were multiple spring boot application getting executed (using same java). I stopped all of them and tried..it worked

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading slash:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91
```

to:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91
```

Comment: please include in the original answer the output of `gradle myProject:bootRun --stacktrace`